# Adding a block to the page but not declaring it in hook_block_info()

Tags: 7, blocks

I have inherited some code from a contractor. This code adds a block to `page_content` but it is not defined in `hook_block_info()`.

We then have the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function erepair_blocks_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    ...
    case 'page_content':
      $block['content'] = page_content();
      break;
    ...
  }
  return $block;
}
```

This block is then displaying on some certain pages but I can't work out how.

So I have looked into the database and have found an entry for the block in the table.

It is safe to presume that they have either:

- executed some sql to add the block (but did not do it in an install file)
- had an entry in `hook_block_info()` added the block to the page then deleted the deceleration in `hook_block_info()`

I imagine what ever they have done is not best practice. Is there anything else they could have done (we are not using features).

Comment: What's in the `page_content()` function?

Answer (score 0):

The block may be positioned using the [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module, or via custom code in about a million places. What you can do is temporarily modify the [template_preprocess_block()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) function in block.module, identify the block you're looking for by looking at the data in $variables['block'], and then looking at the output of debug_backtrace() to see the callstack and find the place the block is coming from.